# Android - how to set value progressbar in java

Tags: android

My Layout

[image]

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/orange"
    android:secondaryProgress="55" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_progress_bar2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/purple"
    android:secondaryProgress="98" />
```

hello , i want to ask , how i can set value " android:secondaryProgress= " from java coding with different variable ?

thanks

Comment: Use the [setSecondaryProgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setSecondaryProgress(int)) method